# Show only first and last line from traceback

Tags: python, dsl

I've build a little internal DSL with python. I'm using `assert` vor validation. If the end user types a wrong parameter the dsl should report whats wrong. At the moment this looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/maskedtimefilter_test/FilterDSL_test.py", line 63, in test_dsl_validation
    input(0): self.regular
  File "/Users/sh/reetz/pythonpath/maskedtimedata/maskedtimefilter.py", line 885, in __lshift__
    kwargs = self.dsl_validation(kwargs)
  File "/Users/sh/reetz/pythonpath/maskedtimedata/maskedtimefilter.py", line 1483, in dsl_validation
    check_if_valid(parameter)
  File "/Users/sh/reetz/pythonpath/maskedtimedata/dsl.py", line 47, in kernel_a
    def kernel_a (x): assert isinstance(x, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)), "kernel must be a list."
AssertionError: kernel must be a list.
```

But the end users are engineers and no computer scientists. Therefore a minimal Traceback is handy. ***Is it possible to shrink the Traceback to the essential information*** (where is the failure and what's the cause) ***like this?:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/maskedtimefilter_test/FilterDSL_test.py", line 63, in test_dsl_validation
    input(0): self.regular
AssertionError: kernel must be a list.
```

Reluctantly I'd like to use normal prints!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not return the traceback data as an array and just work back from that?

```
import traceback
try:
     codethatwillthrowanexception()
except:
     exceptiondata = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
     exceptionarray = [exceptiondata[-1]] + exceptiondata[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 7):

Somewhere in your call stack you can do this:

```
try:
    my_function_that_can_raise_exception()
except Exception: #or AssertionError
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc(limit=1)
```

`limit` is the depth of how many stack trace entries you want to show. (in your case, 1)

demo:

```
In [21]: def f():
    ...:     assert False == True, 'Assertion!'
    ...:     

In [22]: try:
    ...:     f()
    ...: except Exception:
    ...:     import traceback
    ...:     traceback.print_exc(limit=1)
    ...:     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-22-78f9db8d5188>", line 2, in <module>
    f()
AssertionError: Assertion!
```

read more at [`traceback` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html).

Answer (score 1):

As the first part of the traceback is just what you called, you could so something simple, like:

```
try: 
    input(0): self.regular # base call
except AssertionError as ae: # catch the exception
    print(ae) # print out the message
```

You can `print` out whatever you think would be useful in the `except` block.

Alternatively, you could do something more complex with the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html).